# addEvenListener doesn't work on dynamic button - javascript

Tags: javascript, button, addeventlistener

So I'm currently busy with learning JavaScript. I created some dynamic buttons and I tried to add an addEvenListener to it. But it doesn't work and I can't figure it out why it doesn't work. I'm just testing some stuff and I try to create buttons with values from the localstorage. It is almost working, only the addEvenListener isn't working. I just want a simple alert with the key from the localstorage.

```
for (var i = 0; i <= localStorage.length-1; i++) {
    var categoryButton = document.createElement('input');
    categoryButton.setAttribute('class', 'forumMenu');
    categoryButton.setAttribute('type', 'button');
    categoryButton.setAttribute('name', localStorage.key(i));
    categoryButton.setAttribute('value', localStorage.key(i));
    categoryButton.setAttribute('id', localStorage.key(i));
    categoryButton.addEventListener('click', function(col){
    alert(col);
}(localStorage.key(i)),true);
    forumMenu.appendChild(categoryButton);
}
```

Does anyone know why it doesn't work?

Comment: Is it because you try to add an event listener to the button _before_ you add it to them DOM?

Comment: what is "col" argument in handler function? It may be the problem.

Comment: well the col is just a random name I came up with, but It represent the value I want to show in the alert

Comment: somethinghere, so how do I fix that?

Comment: You should have a look at [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/218196)

Comment: @somethinghere no, that's not the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not passing a function to `EventTarget.addEventListener()`. You're immediately executing and passing the result of this:

```
function (col) {
  console.log(col);
}(localStorage.key(i))
```

... which is [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined). You can ammend that by using the following syntax:

```
categoryButton.addEventListener('click', (function(col) { 
   // return a function to addEventListener
   return function(){
      console.log(col);
   }
})(localStorage.key(i)),true);
```

Here's a demo:

```js
var input;
for (var i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
  input = document.createElement('input');
  input.type = "button"
  input.value = i;
  input.addEventListener('click', function(i) {
    // return a function to addEventListener
    return function() {
      console.log(i);
    }
  }(i), true);
  document.body.appendChild(input);
}
```

Comment: This works great, but I have a special div in my html for the buttons. how can I add those buttons to that div?

Comment: Replace `document.body` with the appropriate element. That demo doesn't deal with `localStorage` either. It's merely intended as a simple sample for adding a handler in a loop.

Comment: I noticed it, but wen I try to change the document.body, the eventlistener won't work again. I changed document.body to document.getElementById("forumMenu");

Comment: @Jari your code suggest that you already have a direct reference to `forumMenu`. I couldn't say why it's not working. I've provided a minimal, functioning code sample. You must adapt it to your needs or provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

You stored the value in the `id` attribute, so just use it:

```
 for (var i = 0; i <= localStorage.length-1; i++) {
    var categoryButton = document.createElement('input');
    categoryButton.setAttribute('class', 'forumMenu');
    categoryButton.setAttribute('type', 'button');
    categoryButton.setAttribute('name', localStorage.key(i));
    categoryButton.setAttribute('value', localStorage.key(i));
    categoryButton.setAttribute('id', localStorage.key(i));

    categoryButton.addEventListener('click', function () {alert(this.getAttribute('id'));});
 document.body.appendChild(categoryButton);
 }
```

In the event handler, `this` references the `<input>` element itself, so you can just retrieve the attribute value.

Comment: Please **explain** the changes you made and why/how it solves the problem.

Comment: You certainly don't "have to" store data in the id. And I'd argue that storing arbitrary data in the id is a bad pattern.

Comment: I don't say you "have to", just use what it is already stored. I don't the goal, perhaps store the id is better than the value.

Comment: Oh sorry, I guess my mind inserted a "to" there. Btw, `this.id` would be a simpler way to get the value.

Comment: @FelixKling as well as a bunch of `setAttribute()` calls for values exposed as properties... but that comes from the OP's code.

Answer (score -2):

Thats because you are assigning that eventlistener to an object that is not still in the DOM (thats because you created this element after the DOM was loaded)

Try this:

```
categoryButton.onclick = function(col){
    alert(col);
}
```

You can either declare a function to a var and then reasign this function to the event handler:

```
var myFunction = function(){
    alert("I'm a function");
}

myElement.onclick = myFunction;
```

Comment: So you believe that `addEventListener` only works if the element is in the document? Why? And why shouldn't that apply to `onclick` as well?

Comment: Well, if you want to "click" the element, it must be in the document, isn't it? I figured out he was trying to add this element after the page is loaded.

Comment: Sure, one cannot click the element before its in the document, but you can bind an event handler as soon as you have a reference to it. However I'm still curious why you think that onclick would work (and addEventListener wouldn't).